# Swift Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

Im trying to make a Zomato clone in SwiftUI. The error occurs when I try to loop through an item in the Firebase Firestore DB. The error occurs in this code:

```
let product = Product(name: productName, price: productPrice)
```

Here's the entire code: https://github.com/MysteryCoder456/VegieMato/blob/backend/VegieMato/TabViews/HomeView.swift#L57

Comment: Don't post links to GitHub, paste the *relevant* code directly in the question.

Comment: @pawello2222 that link is only pointing to the file in which the error is in.

Comment: Still, please paste your code directly. See [Is showing a link to GitHub source code acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374761/is-showing-a-link-to-github-source-code-acceptable)

Comment: The reason you should not include include links as they can break over time or get outdated. If that happens then it invalidates the entire question for future readers. If you must include a link, also include a snippet of the actual code in the question so it won't loose context if the link breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your productName and productPrice values would be interpreted as Any data type since the prod value has been defined as [String:Any]. So it has to properly casted before creating Product instance.

```
if let productName = prod[“name”] as? String, 
   let productPrice = prod[“price”] as? Int {
   let product = Product(name: productName, price: productPrice)
   productObjects.append(product) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `productObjects` is declared as a `let` constant and needs to be a `var` if you want to append items to it.

```
let productObjects: Array<Product> = [] // <--- Change to a var
    for prod in vendorProducts {
        let productName = prod["name"]
        let productPrice = prod["price"]
        let product = Product(name: productName, price: productPrice)
        productObjects.append(product)
}
```